# Setting Tab Leaders in Adobe Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When setting tabs in Adobe Illustrator CS6, when I apply a leader to a tab, then add another tab, it puts that leader on the new tab but removes it from the original tab. Is there a way to leave the leaders where I put them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just one of many quirks in AI. You have to define the tabs, then go back and set leaders once they are all defined.